# How to publish a connected app (the replacement for Remote Access settings)

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, remote-access, canvas

So I am trying to setup a remote access piece for using OAuth for a rails app. Remote Access in this org seems to have been removed and replaced by the new Connected Apps feature. When I create a connected app in there I get no option of publishing the app which means I am a little dead in the water.

Any ideas? I have tried on numerous orgs with all settings filled in (so I am attempting to reduce error by only filling in the required fields). Seems a bit odd that there is no help or any information., I have also raised a case with Salesforce but thought you guys might be quicker ;-)

Paul

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out ? i'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: Still nothing yet from Sf support, will update everyone when I find anything further out.And will add bounty tomorrow when it becomes available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I was just attending the webinar on canvas apps and as an aside they answered the question we've been burning to understand.

To publish a connected app, you must first establish a namespace for your development org. You can do this under setup -> create -> packages -> developer settings edit

Once you have saved a namespace, you'll see the publish button.

This is a SERIOUS usability bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes a serious flaw in usability (also I have issues trying to understand the need for it). But hey, working now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!! would have struggled a lot if i wouldnt have seen this

Comment: Hi. I'd just like to add that in order to get the "Connected Apps" option to appear when selecting components for your  package you have to not only create the namespace but assign the package that will be managed. It is possible to create the namespace but delay the actual assigning of the package to be managed but if you do this you won't be able to add the connected app to your package.

Answer (score 1):

With Summer '13 comes the ability to package Canvas Apps.  Because of this, you no longer need to Publish the app as you did prior to Summer '13 and Hence the publish button is gone forever.

Instead, simply create a package and add the Canvas App to the package (Canvas Apps are listed under Connected Apps in the component selector).  Once you have added it to the package, simply upload your package.

Note, Canvas Apps (and Connected Apps) can only be added to a Managed Package.