# Not getting a refresh_token after switching to Connected Apps

Tags: connected-apps, oauth2

I recently moved my codebase onto a new development org, and had to switch from "Remote Access" configuration to "Connected Apps" for my OAuth2 Web Services flow.

After getting everything set up, I found that I was no longer getting a refresh token in response to my request.  The access_token works, but I assume it will eventually expire.

Is this because my Connected App configuration is still in a "Pending" state?  I'm not ready to establish a namespace for development (a requirement for publishing a Connected App, according to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3941/450)), and I assume that's why the app is listed as Pending.

Comment: It does appear that you have to commit to a namespace first. But why not just pick one, and if you change your mind later, just spin up a new dev org with the one you really want and migrate everything over to it? Not ideal, but may get you unstuck at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it might not have anything to do with the namespace.

After configuring a namespace, it still wasn't working.  I took a closer look at the "Selected OAuth Scopes" section, and determined that **I needed to enable "Perform requests on your behalf at any time" in order to get the refresh token**.